# Changing text color onclick doesn't work in some texts

Tags: javascript, button, colors, onclick, textcolor

I used the following code in my website:

```
<a href="#" 
onclick="javascript:document.body.style.backgroundColor='#000000'; 
document.body.style.backgroundImage='none'; 
document.body.style.color='#F8F8F8'; 
document.body.style.fontColor='#FFFFFF';"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
```

When i click in the image, the background of the site changes to black and the color of the text changes to white. The problem is, some text doesn't change. Titles and menus remind unchanged. Any ideas?

[Here you can check my blog](https://traduccionesisekai.blogspot.com/) and see for yourself the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting de color in body, but the components which the color isn't changing already have color, and by the CSS logic, the lower prevails. So you have two options, remove the pre-existing color or change the JS to change the color from the specifics components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't remove the pre-existing color or else the text become red because of the hyperlink. Any ideas how i can change the color of that specific component? For example, the css code for the title of the post is: h2.entry-title a{
    color: #222222;
}

Comment: I think it would be better find the component that are with the font color defined and add class, this way you could do something like document.getElementsByClassName('class') to get all components and in a loop change the colors. I don't know if this is the best course of action, but it is a possibility.